# Drupal is going Symfony. Would WordPress benefit from doing the same?

Tags: php

If WordPress would do the same, would it lose much in performance?

Comment: I think this is overly hypothetical. Symfony is extensive (it seems) code base with multiple function. WordPress is extensive code base with multiple functions. There is no way to guess impact on performance of some theoretical mix in unknown proportions of two extensive codebases.

Answer (score 1):

Before trying to figure out if it would hurt performance (yes, it probably would), one should ask what the benefit of switching to Symfony would be.  I have no idea, since I haven't worked with Symfony.

In general, less code and fewer levels of abstraction are better. For example, WordPress uses a very thin DB layer, instead of an ORM.

Answer (score 0):

*IMO, all these frameworks do one thing:*

> **Turn Developers into users.**

And I think that's bad.

Comment: Maybe, but they also improve the quality of the code, which let's face it - WP lacks...

Comment: Not all frameworks are the same, Symfony and Zend are really the only enterprise level PHP based solutions, and Symfony in particular is modeled after ruby.